# ZPL Programming - Print labels with "pause after every label"

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl, bartender

We are using a ZEBRA GX430t printer, bartender and printing from a third party custom built interface.

What we need is to change the printing settings to be able to print our labels with a pause after each label (e.g. a label prints, when removed by a user the printer sensor picks this up and dispenses the next label in the queue and so on)

To date, I have entered the two stated lines of ZPL programming on the Zebra GX430t manual (`^XA^MMP^XZ^XA^JUS^XZ`) into printing preferences > custom commands. When printing directly from bartender this works. However when printing from our custom built interface (developed using C#) it doesn’t work.

Any support/solution on how I can get this to function via the custom printing interface would be helpful.

Comment: If you could supply the c# code, that might be useful. One question, is this anything to do with Morans is Cheltenham, UK?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for ZPL](https://files.tracerplus.com/public/docs/3rdparty/manuals/ZPL_Vol1.pdf),

```
^XA^MMP^XZ
```

sets the **Print Mode** to **Peel-off**, and

```
^XA^JUS^XZ
```

Simply saves the current settings to the EEPROM so that they persist after power off.

Given that this input works from [BarTender](https://www.seagullscientific.com/) we can assume that it is a valid command. Therefore, unsurprisingly we know that the problem lies with your custom software developed using C#.

Without seeing the source code for the software it is difficult to say anything more useful. However, I suspect your third-party software was written and tested without the full scope of ZPL in mind and is stripping or otherwise [munging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)) the data so that it can no longer be interpreted correctly by your device.

Comment: Hi, 

The below code is the latest version of code we tried. 

` public ActionResult PrintDocument(PrintViewModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
using (var engine = new engine (true))
{
LabelFormatDocument format = engine.Documents.Open(model SelectedDocument);

format.PageSetup.MediaHandling.Action = MediaHandlingActions.WaitForLabelTakenSensor;
format.PageSetUp.MediaHandling.Occurence = MediaHandlingOccurance.AfterEveryPage; `

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726249/zpl-programming-print-labels-with-pause-after-every-label#comment91035420_51727731)  to [@Jodrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659190/jodrell) answer, i can see that you are trying to set the **MediaHandling** of the Label Template, and you mention you have entered the two stated lines of ZPL programming on the Zebra GX430t manual into printing preferences > custom commands. When printing directly from bartender this works but not from the C#.

I suspect your C# code is overriding the printer custom command.

```
public ActionResult PrintDocument(PrintViewModel model) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        using (var engine = new engine (true)) 
        { 
            LabelFormatDocument format = engine.Documents.Open(model SelectedDocument); 
            format.PageSetup.MediaHandling.Action = MediaHandlingActions.WaitForLabelTakenSensor; 
            format.PageSetUp.MediaHandling.Occurence = MediaHandlingOccurance.AfterEveryPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you try to set it the **MediaHandlingAction** to **DriverSettings**?

Remove **WaitForLabelTakenSensor** and **AfterEveryPage** then make sure your printer have that two lines of custom commands.

```
format.PageSetup.MediaHandling.Action = MediaHandlingActions.DriverSettings
```

Comment: Hi Jordell, yes, we were able to achieve this function by changing the driver settings. Thanks for your response.