how do I use ZPL commands to add a two second delay between labels. (zebra programing language)
I have a zp506 printer and I was hoping to find a way to add a small delay between labels when printing. If this can be done in printing preferences, fantastic, otherwise I assume I have to use zpl commands to achieve that.
Best I found in settings is to use peel off mode so that it waits to sense if the label has been removed before printing the next one. Not exactly what im hoping for.

Afaik, there is no such command

Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Delphi Coder is correct, I think. The closest match is peel off mode. See "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726249/zpl-programming-print-labels-with-pause-after-every-label"
